# \mbox{ } + \makeatletter causes "LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}." error

Tags: vertical-alignment, positioning, vertical-spacing

I'd like to keep a section of **text** together with a companion **thin blue underline**, e.g:
[image]

On occasion, the text "**Notes for 'The Gift'**" is separated from the **thin blue underline** which occurs on the subsequent page. The code to create both the **text** and **thin blue underline** is:

```
 \makeatletter
\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-2.3\baselineskip\noindent\textcolor{midnightblue}{\rule{.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}}\par\vskip\baselineskip}
\makeatother
```

where \notesname is defined as:

```
\renewcommand{\notesname}{\textcolor{midnightblue}{Notes for ‘\textit{<$title>}’}}
```

I attempted to use **\mbox** to keep the **text** and **thin blue underline** together on the following page by embracing the above code with **\mbox**:

```
\mbox{%    % <-- Added
\makeatletter
\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-2.3\baselineskip\noindent\textcolor{midnightblue}{\rule{.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}}\par\vskip\baselineskip}
\makeatother
}    % <-- Added
```

however, the

> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

occurs upon compile.

Any and all thoughts as to how to keep the "**Notes for 'The Gift'**" text together with the companion **thin blue underline** would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

> **MWE Update** 17 Dec 2021 @ 12 noon: After a bit of a delay, I've added the following code to demonstrate what I've been advised will NOT work. For now, the \mbox{ } command has been commented out below to show what happens when the \theendnotes command is executed.

```
% !TEX TS-program = Arara 
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes, shell: yes } 
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on, shell: yes } 
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on, shell: yes } 

\documentclass[12pt,oneside,dvipsnames]{book}   

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % fontenc package enables use of Type 1 fonts

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{midnightblue}{RGB}{26,26,112} 

\renewcommand{\notesname}{\textcolor{midnightblue}{Notes for `\textit{The Gift}'}}

%___________________ Define \enoteformat ___________________
\makeatletter
\def\enoteformat{%
  \rightskip\z@ \leftskip\z@ \parindent=1.8em
  \leavevmode{\setbox\z@=\lastbox}\llap{\@Alph\theenmark.\enskip}%
}
\makeatother

%___________________ Define \enoteheading ___________________
% \mbox{%    % <-- IF Added, error occurs
\makeatletter
\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname
  \@mkboth{\notesname}{\notesname}}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-2.7\baselineskip\noindent\textcolor{midnightblue}{\rule{.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}}\par\vskip\baselineskip}
\makeatother
% }    % <-- IF Added, error occurs

\begin{document}

\noindent

Over millions of years, plant photosynthesis would produce enormous volumes of carbon-rich biomass that then would die and accumulate.\footnote{@\,Ibid. (Henry, 2013)}

\theendnotes                % Print the endnotes

\end{document}
```

In light of the comments from **daleif** and **David Carlisle**, I've decided to attempt a different solution. By moving the **thin blue underline** beneath the **text** "**Notes for 'The Gift'**" upwards to be closer to the **text** thus hopefully eliminating the page separation issue between the **text** and the **thin blue underline**.

To do this, I adjusted the above **\enoteheading** code **\vskip-2.3** to **\vskip-2.7** which places the **thin blue underline** *directly* beneath the **text** "**Notes for 'The Gift'**", hopefully eliminating the page separation issue, e.g:

[image]

I'd like to thank **daleif** and **David Carlisle** for their comments that guided me to think of another solution, and although not a strictly coding solution, hopefully will accomplish the desired result.

To **daleif** and **David Carlisle**, if you'd like to submit a formal answer as a 'solution', I'll check your 'solution' to give you credit for your comments.

Thank you both for your help with this issue.

Comment: You cannot have `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` inside a macro. They always go out side. Additionally, please always post full minimal examples instead of these sniplets that we cannot test without having to add code.

Comment: apart from the fact that you can not use makeatletter in an mbox, you can not use marks in an ,box or vskip or section headings, and the box forms a local group so the definition of `\enoteheading` would be discarded at the end of the group before it is used. You only posted a fragment it is impossible to guess what this is intended to do.

Comment: @daleif and David Carlisle, if you'd like to submit a formal answer as a 'solution', citing your comments above, I'll check your 'solution' to give you credit for your comments. Without your comments, I would have spent much more time looking for a solution when all I needed to do (or should have done) was make a cosmetic adjustment to the code. Thank you both again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `\makeatletter` in an `\mbox` (or any command, it has to be used at the outer level). Also you can not use marks in an box or vskip or section headings as marks need to be in the outer level so they can migrate to the page head, and vertical space and section headings requir vertical mode, so do not work in `\mbox` which forces singl-line hmode.

The box forms a local group so the definition of `\enoteheading` would be discarded at the end of the group before it is used.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!